# sed command to print paragraphs after a pattern

Tags: sed, paragraphs

I have a log file where data entries are as follows: Each entry starts with `time:`
Now I want to print only the entries after a specific time.  For example, after `time : 20130309235926`, I want to print all records, so in my case, it should print the last 2 records.

Is there a sed command for doing this?

```
time: 20130309235926
dn: 
changetype: modify
-
replace: modifiersname
modifiersname: 
 dc=
-
replace: modifytimestamp
modifytimestamp: 20130310045926Z
-

time: 20130309235959
dn:
changetype: modify
-
replace: modifiersname
modifiersname: 
 dc=
-
replace: modifytimestamp
modifytimestamp: 20130310045926Z
-

time: 20130308025010
dn: 
changetype: modify
-
replace: modifiersname
modifiersname: 
 dc=
-
replace: modifytimestamp
modifytimestamp: 20130310045926Z
-
```

Comment: Not sure about `sed`, but `awk` might be useful for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

It depends if the time to find matches exactly or not, because doing aritmethic with `sed` is difficult. For example, for an exact match, this command uses `-n` switch to disable automatic printing and uses a range to print from the line that matches your time until end of file (`$`):

```
sed -n '/time:[ ]*20130309235926/,$ p' infile
```

---

**EDIT** to fix previous command:

```
sed -n '

  ## When found a blank line between a line with your time and end of file,
  ## jump to label "a".
  /time:[ ]*20130309235926/,$ { 
    /^[ ]*$/ ba
  };

  ## Skip all lines until previous condition be true.
  b;

  ## Label "a".
  :a;

  ## Save all content from next entry until end of file.
  $! { 
    N; 
    ba 
  }; 

  ## Remove extra newline and print.
  s/^\n//; 
  p

' infile
```

---

**EDIT** to add the previous command as a one-line:

```
sed -n '/time:[ ]*20130309235926/,$ { /^[ ]*$/ ba }; b; :a; $! { N; ba }; s/^\n//; p' infile
```

Comment: This includes the first record.  Maybe you can post-process to cut that record out.

Comment: @paddy: You are right. I didn't realize of that. I will try to fix it.

Comment: Actually i don't want the first record, Anyway to do that?

Comment: @user2162950: Edited version skips first record. In what way doesn't work as you expect?

Comment: I am getting the following error : sed: $! { is not a recognized function.

Comment: Thanks but this is the error: sed: The label /time:[ ]*20130309235926/,$ { /^[ ]*$/ ba }; b; :a; $! { N; ba }; s/^\n//; p is greater than eight characters.
i Am not sure why its throwing that error.

Comment: @user2162950: Are you using `GNU sed`. If not, you must put each instruction in separate lines (or at least the instruction with the label). Did you test if the script split in lines work for you?

Comment: When i spilt it , i get the earlier error:

sed: $! { is not a recognized function

Comment: @user2162950: Try to put all the script between single quotes in a file, for example `script.sed`, and run it like: `sed -nf script.sed infile`. Otherwise I can't think of a way solve it because I can't reproduce it.

Comment: @user2162950: Test the script with one instruction, when it works add another one and so on, debug it yourself. Also you can try **glenn jackman's** answer.

Answer (score 1):

I like perl for doing paragraph-y things:

```
perl -00 -ne '$t = (/time: (\d+)/)[0]; print if $t gt "20130309235926"'
```

The `-00` flag provides the input in paragraphs (separated by empty lines)